# D3: how to select the div from multiple divs with the same class by the inner html in D3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have drawn a series divs looks like button through D3 as shown below[image: A continous series of years buttons]

I used this code

```
var years = [1975, 1976,...... ,2016]
var buttons = d3.select("body")
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("class", "years_buttons")
                    .selectAll("div")
                    .data(years)
                    .enter()
                    .append("div")
                    .text(function(d) {
                        return d;
                    });
```

What I wanted to achieve is to select any button(with out clicking just by code using year name as a unique value) to change the styling of the button. I tried the following code but it didn't worked.

```
d3.select(".years_buttons")
  .selectAll("div")
  .filter(function(d){return d.innerText == '2002'})
  .attr('color','white')
```

can any body help me out in this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your filter function, `d` refers to the data, not the element. Also, `.attr('color', 'white')` would assign `color="white"` as an element attribute, not a style. You're looking for `.style()`. To filter properly, in your original render, you might assign the data as an id as well as text, and then use that to select your target element:

```js
var years = [1975, 1976, 2016]
var buttons = d3.select("body")
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("class", "years_buttons")
                    .selectAll("div")
                    .data(years)
                    .enter()
                    .append("div")
                    .attr('id', function(d) {
                        return 'id' + d;
                    })
                    .text(function(d) {
                        return d;
                    });
                    
d3.select('#id1975')
  .style('color', 'white')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I added the string `'id'` before the data: html ids should not begin with a number, so be sure to add a string that, combined with the data, will be unique on the page.

Comment: Despite you being correct about `style`, you don't need to add IDs here, just use the datum: https://jsfiddle.net/jafgkhf6/